# how to set default values for attributes in xml

Tags: xml, dtd

How do i set default values for attributes in xml. Consider below test.xml.
An attribute 'gender' with default value 'male' has been defined for element 'to'.
I am however unable to retrieve it using xmlstarlet. Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE message [
  <!ELEMENT message (to,from,subject,text)>
  <!ELEMENT to       (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT from     (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT subject  (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT text     (#PCDATA)>
  <!ATTLIST to gender CDATA "male">
]>

<message>
  <to>Dave</to>
  <from>Susan</from>
  <subject>Reminder</subject>
  <text>Dont forget to buy milk on the way home.</text>
</message>
```

xmlstarlet cmd: (doesnt print anything to stdout)

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "//message/to" -v "@gender" -n test.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the `gender` attribute with the default value is fine. It must be something with the `sel` command of xmlstartlet. Either that or how you're trying to use it. I don't know much about xmlstarlet though. You can use XSLT to verify the default value:

**XML Input** (test.xml)

```
<!DOCTYPE message [
<!ELEMENT message (to,from,subject,text)>
<!ELEMENT to       (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from     (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT subject  (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT text     (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST to gender CDATA "male">
]>
<message>
  <to>Dave</to>
  <from>Susan</from>
  <subject>Reminder</subject>
  <text>Dont forget to buy milk on the way home.</text>
</message>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="to/@gender"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command Line and Output** (xmlstarlet on Windows)

```
C:\apps\xmlstarlet-1.4.2>xml tr test.xsl test.xml
male
```